# "Promote to front page" to other than front page

Tags: nodes, 7

Is it possible to push node summaries (teaser text) onto pages other than the "Front Page"?
I see the option "Promoted to front page" but is there a workaround for promoting them to  sub-pages as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Promoted to front page" can be used as a views filter. So you could create views based on that (so it displays node teasers that have a certain taxonomy and are "Promoted to front page").

Another simple way to mimic "Promoted to front page" is to add a taxonomy select field to your content types, and then the taxonomy pages would display the specified content.

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 6):

Alternative to mtro's answer (which is correct), I find it also useful to use the "flags" module. http://drupal.org/project/flag

Create a flag like "promote to sub-page" then create a "sub-page" view which selects nodes with that flag.

Answer (score 2):

Besides, you can also use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

With Rules, you can specify the condition and action on a node is prompted to front.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a Boolean field as a simple checkbox and then filter Views on that.